# How to use a tbody as the root react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, knockout.js

I have a big complicated `<table>` with lots of bindings to another javascript framework (knockout). I'm trying to convert a portion of it into React.

```
<table>
    <tbody id="lots_of_legacy_knockout"> ... </tbody>
    <tbody id="I_want_this_in_React"></tbody>
</table>
```

However, this tries to put a `<tbody>` root element inside the `<tbody>` container:

```
const Tbody = () => (
    <tbody>
        <tr />
        <tr />
        <tr />
    </tbody>
);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Tbody />,
    document.getElementById('I_want_this_in_React')
);
```

And this results in an error because React wants a unique root element:

```
const Tbody = () => ([
    <tr />,
    <tr />,
    <tr />,
]);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Tbody />,
    document.getElementById('I_want_this_in_React')
);
```

How can I accomplish this without rewriting the entire root `<table>` element in React?

Is there a way to combine the react root and the react container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now use `React.Fragment`:

```
const Tbody = () => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <tr />
        <tr />
        <tr />
    </React.Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Tbody />,
    document.getElementById('I_want_this_in_React')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will result in:

```
// Invalid HTML
<tbody id="I_want_this_in_React">
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</tbody>
```

which is not valid HTML.

Since React requires rendered components to have exactly zero siblings, I don't think there is a way to do this with React.

For example, you would need to wrap the `<Tr />` components with *some* HTML element, which also wouldn't be valid HTML.

```
// Invalid HTML
<tbody>
  <span>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </span>
</tbody>
```

Is there a way you can instead separate out the `<tbody>` intended for React into it's own `<table>`?

If so, you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<table id="lots_of_legacy_knockout">
    <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>

<table id="I_want_this_in_React"></table>
```

React:

```
const Tbody = () => (
    <tbody>
        <tr />
        <tr />
        <tr />
    </tbody>
);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Tbody />,
    document.getElementById('I_want_this_in_React')
);
```

Or, nest the `<table>`:

HTML:

```
<table id="lots_of_legacy_knockout">
    <tbody>...</tbody>
    <table id="I_want_this_in_React"></table>
</table>
```

React:

```
const Tbody = () => (
    <tbody>
        <tr />
        <tr />
        <tr />
    </tbody>
);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Tbody />,
    document.getElementById('I_want_this_in_React')
);
```

Comment: Hmm. There's no way for me to split the contents out of the table. I wonder if it's possible to render the react component outside the table as you suggest, and then pull it into the table once it's rendered?
`$('#I_want_this_in_React').html($('#react_tbody').html());`

Comment: I would think it's not possible and would go against core React principles.  Let React manage the relevant DOM for you.  Rendering the component out to another component, and using jQuery to copy it's contents is just objectively bad practice, and I'm not even sure how you would get jQuery to do that since how is jQuery going to know when the Component was rerendered?  My advice: Either separate out your piece of the table out, or bring the entire `<table>` into React.  If this hasn't answered your question, let me know.

Comment: You can also nest a table within another table if that works for you.

Comment: My use case is a lot more complicated than the example I gave. I can't separate out the table and I can't practically convert the entire thing to React. Thanks for the tip about tables inside tables, I'll start investigating that.